# Two functions calling each other, send message when finally done

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, async-await, callback

I have 2 functions that call each other. How to send a message when all conditions are met?

My code:

```
const func1 = async (arg) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  const response = await axios_Func({ graphQL query });
  console.log(`${response.data.name} - ${table_id}`);
  return func2({ query: graphQL_query, table_id });
}

func2 = async (result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getAllTables({ query: tables(123) });
  let prod = await getAllTables({ query: tables(321) });
  let prod_id = new Set();
  result.data.data.table.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d. connector != null && !(d.name in dev))
      prod_id.add(prod[d.name]["id"]);
  });
  prod_id = [...prod_id];
  prod_id.map((x) => createOne({ query: graphQL_query(x) });
});

const callback = () => console.log("all done");
```

Right now my function returns:

```
xyz - M5WBmnWs 
abc - QrqJ91Rq
qwe - VP0B0KEt
```

How do I call `callback`? And make my output look like this:

```
xyz - M5WBmnWs 
abc - QrqJ91Rq
qwe - VP0B0KEt
all done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get exactly what you are trying to do but this should work:

```
const func1 = async (arg) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  const response = await axios_Func({ graphQL query });
  console.log(`${response.data.name} - ${table_id}`);
  await func2({ query: graphQL_query, table_id });
}

func2 = async (result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getAllTables({ query: tables(123) });
  let prod = await getAllTables({ query: tables(321) });
  let prod_id = new Set();
  result.data.data.table.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d. connector != null && !(d.name in dev))
      prod_id.add(prod[d.name]["id"]);
  });
  prod_id = [...prod_id];
  prod_id.map((x) => createOne({ query: graphQL_query(x) });
  // if createOne is a promise you need:
  // return Promise.all(prod_id.map((x) => createOne({ query: graphQL_query(x) }));
});

const callback = () => console.log("all done");

const execute = async () => {
  await func1()
  callback()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Await the function call and call `callback` at the end:

```
await func1();
callback();
```